# Property injection of object via Unity into Startup turns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

**NOTE**: I originally entitled this page "*Method* injection of object via Unity into Startup turns null"; All other references to *method* injection should be read as *property* injection.

I am using unity in an Asp.Net MVC5 project, which I originally installed via the Unity.Mvc5 nuget package. Since I have moved AspNet Identity stuff into it's own project, I am struggling to give its custom ApplicationUserManager access to DataProtectionProvider, which is obtainable by MVC applications in Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app), via app.GetDataProtectionProvider(). (If the Identity stuff was still in the web project, I would go about this as suggested by trailmax at: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/  )

I have defined a DataProtectionProviderFactory class, like so:

```
public class DataProtectionProviderFactory : MVC5.Web.Identity.IDataProtectionProviderFactory
{

    private IDataProtectionProvider _dp;
    public void SetProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dp)
    {
        _dp = dp;
    }

    public IDataProtectionProvider GetProvider()
    {
        return _dp;
    }
}
```

and then set up both the Startup class, as well as the ApplicationUserManager class, for method injection via Unity. In the Identity Project, I have:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>
{

    public IDataProtectionProviderFactory DataProtectionProviderFactory { get; set; }
.
.
}
```

And in the Web Project, I have

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public IDataProtectionProviderFactory DataProtectionProviderFactory { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app )
    { 
        DataProtectionProviderFactory.SetProvider(app.GetDataProtectionProvider());
    }
```

}

My UnityConfig.cs file is (basically):

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("Mvc5"));


        container.RegisterType<IDataProtectionProviderFactory, DataProtectionProviderFactory>();
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>, ApplicationUserManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionProperty("DataProtectionProviderFactory"));
        container.RegisterType<Startup>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionProperty("DataProtectionProviderFactory"));

        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<IdentityUser, Guid>, UserStore>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<CustomSigninManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());                     


        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        // Startup.DataProtectionProviderFactory is non-null, after resolving in the following line
        var start = container.Resolve<Startup>();

        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));      

    }
}
```

If I break in RegisterComponents() on the line:

```
        var start = container.Resolve<Startup>();
```

then I can see that Startup.DataProtectionProviderFactory in non-null.

However, when subsequently Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) executes, it's Startup.DataProtectionProviderFactory is null.

## Update

After making initial changes as suggested by mnwsmit, I added an argument of "new Startup()" to the UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() call, yielding the following:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(new Startup());
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;      
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the instance of Startup where you call ConfigureAuth on originate from the container?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. During the normal startup sequence, Startup.Configuration is called, which in turn calls Startup.ConfigureAuth. Pausing in the debugger shows only [External Code] as lower in the call stack. By this time, a browser has been spun up, complete with url pointing to the default route, and I assume this aspect of the startup procedures are being called in response to the first Http request from the browser.


I have not written any code that calls ConfigureAuth, explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of the `Startup` class on which `ConfigureAuth` is called is created by OWIN instead of by Unity. Thus in your setup you end up with two instances of the `Startup` class, one with it's dependency injected, the other not. There is no way to let Unity inject a dependency on the instance created by OWIN (your real startup). You should make a single exception to the rule and use the container as a Service Locator to get the `DataProtectionProviderFactory` instance and make sure the `Startup` class gets that instance and uses it. For example like below:

```
public static void RegisterComponents(Startup startup)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // registration

    startup.DataProtectionProviderFactory = container.Resolve<IDataProtectionProviderFactory>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, I've still not got things working, and DataProtectionProviderFactory is still null when Startup.ConfigureAuth() is executing. Meanwhile, inside of RegisterComponents(Startup startup), the line

`startup.DataProtectionProviderFactory = container.Resolve<IDataProtectionProviderFactory>();`

executed as expected. I.e., DataProtectionProviderFactory was non-null.

Comment: To get the application to compile, I changed the line inside Application_Start() (in Global.asax.cs) to


            `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(new Startup());`
from
            `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();`


(Also, in UnityConfig.cs, I removed:

            `container.RegisterType<Startup>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionProperty("DataProtectionProviderFactory"));`

)


 I'm guessing that calling UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(new Startup()) messes things up. Wouldn't we need to register UnityConfig.RegisterComponents with Owin ?

Comment: new Startup() is especially something we want to avoid. I think that you should call `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(this)` in the entry point in the Startup class. However I'm not completely sure how your code looks. Could you add the relevant content of Application_Start() to you question? And does Startup have other relevant code? I'm trying to figure out what the entry point(s) of your app is/are

Comment: I updated the question with the Application_Start code. I tried changing the argument to "this", but that didn't compile.  Thanks for your help, so far.

Comment: No, the line `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(this);` must be in the Startup class. For example in the method `ConfigureAuth`

Comment: OK, that fixes the DataProtectionProviderFactory being null in Startup. Unfortunately, the method injection into ApplicationUserManager is failing. (I assume it would have failed, before, but is only evident now, since I got past the prior sticking point which occurred during the first MVC Request life cycle, for an anonymous user). Any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry, no ideas on that. Ask a new question with details on that?

Comment: Adding a new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() to the IDataProtectionProviderFactory registration got my application to the point of being able to log on, but the ApplicationUserManager.DataProtectionProviderFactory would once again become null during the logoff, and throw an error. I didn't care to investigate further, since switching to constructor injection allowed both log on and log off.